# Swift - Bridging header failed. '*' does not have a member named '*'

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bridging-header

I develop an app that using CommonCrypto library. The problem is I can create an instance in Swift file. My object created using Objective- C. It seems can't create bridging header very well.

Error message

```
/Users/MNurdin/Documents/iOS/xxxxx/Models/Main.swift:15:9: 'CustomObject' does not have a member named 'encrypt'
```

CustomObject.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>
#import "GTMBase64.h"

@interface CustomObject : NSObject
+ (NSString*)encrypt:(NSString*)plainText withKey:(NSString*)key;
@end
```

CustomObject.m

```
#import "CustomObject.h"
@implementation CustomObject
+ (NSString*)encrypt:(NSString*)plainText withKey:(NSString*)key{
    /*--*/
    return result;
}
@end
```

Global.swift

```
var instanceOfCustomObject: CustomObject = CustomObject()
println(instanceOfCustomObject.encrypt("p@$$w0rd","12345678"))
```

Comment: I got this error message, Expressions are not allowed at the top level

Comment: which line? still figuring it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The initial `+` in the declaration indicates that

```
+ (NSString*)encrypt:(NSString*)plainText withKey:(NSString*)key;
```

is a *class method* in Objective-C. You have to call it on the
*class* (or *type* in Swift linguage) itself, not on an instance:

```
let encrypted = CustomObject.encrypt("p@$$w0rd", withKey: "12345678")
```